# Strip tower namespace for inference on a multi-GPU-trained model (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

Good day everybody.

**Description:** following the famous CIFAR-10 tutorial, I train a model on multiple GPUs in a data-parallel fashion, i.e. have several copies of the model graph, each located under its `tf.name_scope()`s `tower_0`, `tower_1` etc., and sharing trainable variables between these scopes.

**My need:** for the sake of simplicity and uniformity of naming the input tensors during inference (e.g. to have the same graph as models which are not trained on multi GPU and thus don't have `tower_N` top name scope in their graphs), I want to strip off the top name scope `tower_N` from the graph when saving ".meta" file.

**What I have tried:**

1. **[didn't work]** e.g. make use of `tf.train.export_meta_graph()` with the argument `export_scope` set to `tower_0`. First of all, this function performes changes on the graph [deeply inside](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py#L979). Hence there's no way I can use it in a finalized graph. Second, if I preparate the whole thing, load `meta_graph.export_scoped_meta_graph()` directly and use it with `unbound_inputs_col_name=None`, I get problems dealing with loading undefined unbound inputs in this case.
2. **[worked but ugly]** when training, leave the model that resides on `GPU:0` sort of "naked", i.e. without its `tower_0` name scope. This way in my graph I will always have exactly one top-level copy of my model which has the desired naming of tensors.

I would appreciate any input, because my task of keeping graph clean when training on several GPUs seems quite natural...